# UNIX wc -l in a xls file with multiple tabs

Tags: linux, unix

I have an xls file, Test.xls in a folder. It has multiple tabs/worksheets within the spreadsheet. I'm wondering, is there any way to list the line counts for each worksheet with a `wc -l unix` command? I am using Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: Test.xls -- worksheets inside the Test.xls - worksheetA,worksheetB,worksheetC,worksheetD -- Required wc -l worksheetA = ? wc -l worksheetB = ? wc -l worksheetC= ? etc

Comment: Your comment should probably be incorporated into the question.

Comment: Although `wc` will give you an answer, there is essentially zero chance that the answer is meaningful.  Newline bytes can appear in integer and decimal numbers, and rows in the spreadsheet won't be marked reliably by a newline, and there's no way to analyze the separate worksheets within the spreadsheet using `wc`.

Answer (score 2):

No.

`wc` only works sensibly on plain text files.  You will need to find or create a program that knows how to open a .xls file and process the data contained there-in.

Comment: I have used wc -l <fileName> it (count the 'l' lines in the file for me) in a file, it worked fine for text file and csv files... any suggestion which program i can create in the unix server to help facilitate the count for xls with multiple worksheets within it